# Multiple ifs and elifs in oneliner python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
a = 0
if 0 < b <= 100:
    a = 10
elif 100 < b <= 1000:
    a = 40
elif 1000 < b <= 5000:
    a = 90
elif 5000 < b <= 10000:
    a = 180
elif 10000 < b <= 20000:
    a = 350
elif 20000 < b <= 100000:
    a = 700
elif 100000 < b <= 300000:
    a = 1400
elif 300000 < b:
    a = 3300
print a
```

Is there any way to reduce it somehow and maybe make one line?

Comment: Thanks for the quick. For the answer, I think I wasn't searching for the correct tags!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
a=10
a= {0 < b <= 100: 10, 100< b <= 1000: 40, 1000 < b <= 5000: 90, 5000 < b <= 10000: 180, 10000 < b <= 20000:350, 20000 < b <= 100000: 700, 100000 < b <= 300000:1400, 300000 < b:3300}.get(True, a)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it too!